# How to allocate a string array in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and made myself a text file with over 10,000 lines. I'm trying to make a string array and insert the first line into the first array, the second line into the second array and so on. Here is what I've done so far:

```
ifstream theFile;
string inputFile;
cin >> inputFile;
theFile.open(inputFile.c_str());
const unsigned int ARRAY_CAP = 64U;

string line;
string *lineArr = new string[ARRAY_CAP];

if (theFile.is_open()) {
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (!theFile.eof()) {
        getline(theFile, line);
        lineArr[i] = line;
        i++;
    }
}
```

A friend of mine told me to allocate the string array because I'm running out of memory, but I'm not even sure how to do that. How could I be able to allocate the string array?

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector<std::string>>`? Also, "while (!theFile.eof())" is not going to do what you want..

Comment: Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and forget about allocation.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I kind of want to know how to allocate arrays, too. My older brother told me that they allocate arrays all the time in college. :/

Comment: To add to the above comments, a `std::vector<std::string>` is a "string array" which is allocated on the heap. So you would create a `std::vector<std::string> lineArr;` and for each new string you'd do `lineArr.push_back(line)`

Comment: @James -- `std::vector` is how we "allocate" arrays in C++.  Whatever college you're referring to is teaching C++ as it was in the early 1990's, not as of how C++ stands today (and frankly for the past 18 years).

Comment: @James In modern C++ you try not to manually allocate arrays because it can lead to memory leaks (particularly in the cases of exceptions). So using a vector is (generally) better.

Comment: @James Then I'd say those teaching at that college probably need to upgrade their knowledge to modern C++ and not stay stuck in the 90's..

Comment: @James: You should get a code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Change your array capacity.  If the text file has 10,000 lines, then your array should have a capacity of 10,000; not 64.  That is assuming one string per text line.

Comment: If you are not going to use `std::vector`, then you will have to do the following when you reach the capacity of the array: 1) allocate a new array of larger capacity; 2) Copy elements from old array to new array; 3) delete old array.  The `std::vector` already does this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with dynamically allocated arrays, you will need to expand them dynamically.

```
unsigned int lines_read = 0U;
std::string text_line;
unsigned int capacity = 4U;
std::string * p_array = new std::string[capacity];
while (std::getline(theFile, text_line))
{
  p_array[lines_read] = text_line;
  ++lines_read;
  if (lines_read > capacity)
  {
     // Allocate new array with greater capacity.
     unsigned int old_capacity = capacity;
     capacity = capacity * 2U;
     std::string p_new_array = new std::string[capacity];
     std::copy(p_array, p_array + old_capacity, p_new_array);
     delete [] p_array;
     p_array = p_new_array;
  }
}
```

The `std::vector` performs similar memory management for you, so you don't have to do the above.